Portable Blender isn't saving text extrusions
I'm using Blender 4.2.3 LTS via a Portable Apps installation on Windows 11 pro. I have a bunch of text objects that are snapped to faces (making a D20). I am extruding the text in the Data > Geometry > Extrude. After I've saved the file, closed out of blender and reopened, the text is no longer extruded. The extrude value of each is set back to zero.
I don't want to convert the text objects to meshes so the I can easily change values/fonts later.
I added a text object with the same settings that's NOT snapped to the surface and it reloads as expected. I'm not sure if I'm missing a setting that would make it behave correctly. Is this expected from the snap feature?

What's "Blender 4.2.3 LTS via a Portable Apps installation on Windows 11 pro"? What does that mean? Portable Blender is the one you download in a zip archive, extract anywhere and run without installing.

That would be a version packed by https://portableapps.com I don't think it has anything to do with the issue at hand, but to be sure, I'd test it out on a regular version just to be sure.

I didn't realize (or forgot) there was a regular portable version, so I have it running via portableapps. So I downloaded the regular portable one (4.3.0) and opened the file, re-extracted some text, saved, closed and reopened and the problem still occurs.

I also just opened the file using a fully installed version and still the extruded text loses its extrusion, so I must be missing some setting to maintain it.
